# HSQLDB - Get last inserted or updated value

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I need to get the last inserted data in HSQLDB.

I think CALL IDENTITY() is supposed to do that, but I always get 0 with it. No idea what's wrong.

Any suggestion?

Comment: post your code and what you have tried so for?

Comment: Please provide DDL for the table to which you're trying to insert dat.a